# TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available

Tags: azure-devops

I am not able to push changes to a repo on Azure Devops.  I keep getting messages of the form:

> TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available from server dev.azure.com/xyz.
> Technical information (for administrator):
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Does this mean there is something wrong with my account?

Comment: What kind of account do you have?

Comment: Where you push the changes to the repo, the VS? If yes, please check if this give any help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tf400324-azure-devops-services-are-not-available-f-1/1316747#T-N1350492

Comment: I am not sure how determine the account type.  I know it is a paid account because I get a monthly bill.

Comment: @Dennis, what have you tried and the result? Have you check the link in pervious comment?